# How to find a property within nested array and return its location

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

Using javascript only, is there a way to locate a property within an array that is itself within another array and return its "path"?

Imagine a hierarchical group of nested arrays much like this example:

```
    var bigBox = [  

        mediumBoxA = [
                smallBoxA = [                  
                         toyA = { toyId : "Blue Ball"},
                         toyb = { toyId : "Pink Ball"}
                    ],

                smallBoxB = [                  
                         toyA = { toyId : "Girl Doll"},
                         toyB = { toyId : "Boy Doll"}
                    ],
            ],

        mediumBoxB = [
                smallBoxA = [                  
                         toyA = { toyId : "Batman"},
                         toyB = { toyId : "Superman"}
                    ],

                smallBoxB = [                  
                         toyA = { toyId : "Lego"},
                         toyB = { toyId : "Soldier"}
                    ],
            ]

   ];
```

Given that, **in the console** I want to be able to search for example: "Batman" and get that it is
located in **bigBox > mediumBoxB > smallBoxA > toyA.**
Again, I'm looking for a JS only solution and something I can implement on the console. No HTML involved.

Now, I know that i could go only by the index number, I used labels on each array such as "smallBox", "toyB", etc.. for explanation purposes.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Use a recursive function that iterate on the array then call himself if a sub-array is found. Pass the current "path" in paramater and if the value is found then print the whole path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented a recursive function, which finds the path and returns it as an array:

```
/**
 * Finds an value and returns the path of nested variable names
 * 
 * @param {obj}       The object to search in
 * @param {search}    The value to search for
 * @param {variables} The relevant variables names or the context object
 * @param {context}   The context object in which to search the variable names
 *
 * @return The found path as an array or null if nothing was found
 */
function getPath(obj, search, variables, context) {

    if(context === undefined) {
        context = window;        
    }

    if(variables === undefined) {
        variables = window;
    }
    if(!Array.isArray(variables)) {
        // if variables is an object, this object is the context
        context = variables;
        // copy the keys to the variables array
        variables = [];
        for(var key in context) {
            if(context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                try {
                    // try to read property
                    context[key];
                    // push key to variable names
                    variables.push(key);
                } catch(e) {
                    // some properties of the window object cannot be read
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getVariableName(variable) {
        for(var i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
            var name = variables[i];
            if(context[name] === variable) {
                // return variable name
                return name;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function _getPath(variable, path) {
        if(typeof variable === 'object') {
            var name = getVariableName(variable);
            if(name) {
                var pathCopy = path.slice(0);
                pathCopy.push(name);
                for(var key in variable) {
                    // recursive call of _getPath
                    var returnedPath = _getPath(variable[key], pathCopy);
                    if(returnedPath) {
                        return returnedPath;
                    }
                }
            }            
        } else if(variable === search) {
            return path;
        }
        // if nothing was found, return null
        return null;
    }

    // now recursively search for the value
    return _getPath(obj, []);
}
```

With the function `getPath` you can do the following:

```
var path = getPath(bigBox, "Batman");
console.log(path.join(" > ")); // logs "bigBox > mediumBoxB > smallBoxC > toyE"
```

If all of your variables are in one object, you can also call the `getPath` function with an additional context argument like this:

```
var path = getPath(context.bigBox, "Batman", context);
```

*I've changed the object `bigBox` a little bit, so that every variable is exactly once in the object.*

#### Here is the **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cbv9b/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can walk through the tree using enumeration, and get the name of each key by simply using the `for x in y` syntax. In each iteration, the key's name is in the value of X. You can use your own preferred recursive or iterative implementation for scanning the tree and constructing a search path, then return the built path once you find your matching value.

That's the naive implementation in any case. There might be some faster ways to do tree searches; I'm not a computer scientist.